# Probability of a run of *k* or more of a subset of categories in *m* multinoulli trials?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a multinoulli distribution of categories $(C_1,C_2,...,C_n)$ with associated probabilities $\left\{p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_n\right\}$ with $\sum _{i=1}^n p_i=1$, is there a tractable way to get the *exact* probability of getting a run of *k* or more of any member of some selected subset of the *C* (e.g. $(C_3,C_5,C_7)$) in *m* trials?

By "run", I mean a series of consecutive draws of the *same* element, where that element is in the desired subset.

I'm currently using existing methods to derive the probability of such a streak for *each* of the elements of the subset, then using inclusion-exlusion on those results, which nets a surprisingly close estimator, but I'd like to get the *exact* probability, with cases for *n* up to 20 or 30, *m* up to 10^5 or so.

I can see that the exact probability can be had by taking the set of PMF for an appropriate multinomial distribution that meets my criteria and "tracing" the possible transitions from sample 1 to 2, 2 to 3, ... m-1 to m, but that's clearly a ridiculous proposition for anything beyond trivial cases.

Thoughts?

Comment: The exact expression for the expected number of run lengths of size $k$ over all objects in the set $A$ you care about  (assuming $m>k$, and including overlapping run lengths as distinct) is: $(m-k+1)\sum_{i\in A}p_i^k$.

Comment: The Goulden-Jackson cluster method will produce a generating function for these probabilities (actually for the probabilities of *avoiding* the $k$-runs but that will give you what you need.)  (The clusters are especially simple in this case because the $k$-runs don't overlap, other than with themselves.) See Kupin and Yuster's paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.5113.pdf).

Comment: @Tad I shall take a look at the reference, thanks @Tad!

Comment: @tad - sadly, that's not going to be much help - it provides a *count* of words, which if all words are equiprobable, would be useful. In my case, they're not (in fact, I'm quite sure I had an e-mail discussion some time ago with the paper author re: ideas to extend to alphabets with differing element probabilities, the response was along the lines of "... not that I can see..."

Comment: The variant in the paper I referenced shows you how to incorporate the probabilities. See section 4. I'll post it tonight if I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the Goulden-Jackson cluster method.  While typically described for counting, this method extends naturally (as described, for example, in section 4 of [Kupin-Yuster](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.5113.pdf)) to a situation where each symbol (or "category" here) has a weight, and the weight of a string is the product of the weights of the symbols.  Of course we take the weight of symbol $i$ to be the probability $p_i$.

Suppose category $i$ has probability $p_i$, and let $A$ denote a subset of the categories.  Let $p(m)$ denote the probability that an $m$-long sequence of trials *avoids* $k_i$-runs of category $i$, for all $i\in A$.  Then the cluster method gives 
$$\sum_{m\ge0}p(m)t^m = \frac1{1-t+\displaystyle\sum_{i\in A}\frac{(p_i t)^{k_i}(1-p_i t)}{(1-(p_it)^{k_i})}}.$$

In your particular case we have $k_i=k$ for each $i$, and we can write the generating function in the following particularly useful form:
$$\sum_{m\ge0}p(m)t^m = \frac1{1-t+\sum_{j>0}(s_{jk}t^{jk}-s_{jk+1}t^{jk+1})}$$
where $s_r=\sum_{i\in A}p_i^r$, the symmetric $r$-th power sum.

You can interpret the generating function as an effective recurrence for $p(m)$, given numerical values for the $p_i$'s:
$$p(m)= \begin{cases}
  1,&m=0;\\
  p(m-1) - \sum_{j>0}s_{jk}\, p(m-j k) + \sum_{j>0}s_{jk+1}\,p(m-jk-1),&m>0
\end{cases}$$

The natural approach is to store both $p(r)$ and $s_r$ for $r=0,\ldots,m$.  Computing $p(r)$ requires looking back at approximately $2r/k$ of the previous values, so this allows you to compute $p(m)$ in $O(m^2|A|/k)$ operations and $O(m+|A|)$ space.

Here are some examples.  For $k=3$ (and arbitrary $A$) the generating function takes the following form:

$$\begin{align}
  \sum_{m\ge0}p(m)=&\: 1+t+t^2+\left(1-s_3\right) t^3\\
   & + \left(1 -2 s_3+s_4\right) t^4\\
   & +\left(1 -3 s_3+2 s_4\right) t^5\\
   & +\left(1+s_3{}^2-4 s_3+3 s_4-s_6\right) t^6\\
   & +\left(1+3 s_3{}^2-2s_4 s_3-5 s_3+4 s_4-2 s_6+s_7\right) t^7\\
   & +\left(1+6 s_3{}^2-6 s_4 s_3-6s_3+s_4{}^2+5 s_4-3 s_6+2 s_7\right) t^8\\
   & +\left(1-s_3{}^3+10 s_3{}^2-12 s_4
   s_3+2 s_6 s_3-7 s_3+3 s_4{}^2+6 s_4-4 s_6+3 s_7-s_9\right) t^9\\
   & +O\left(t^{10}\right)\end{align}.$$

The terms up to $t=3$ are obviously correct: the first time you hit $3$-long runs is at length $3$; the probability of that happening is $\sum_{i\in A}p_i^3=s_3$.  The next few terms can be seen to be correct via inclusion/exclusion, but thereafter using the recurrence (or a symbolic algebra package to expand the Taylor series) seems to be the most straightforward way to compute the values.

As a more specific example, let's keep $k=3$, and let's say $A$ consists of three categories whose probabilities are $4/10$, $3/10$, and $2/10$.  (Note that it doesn't matter how many other categories there are or what their probabilities are.)  We get
$$1+t+t^2+\frac{901 t^3}{1000}+\frac{8373 t^4}{10000}+\frac{967
   t^5}{1250}+\frac{178703 t^6}{250000}+\frac{1321411
   t^7}{2000000}+\frac{61065669 t^8}{100000000}+\frac{282190477
   t^9}{500000000}+\frac{652029649 t^{10}}{1250000000}+O\left(t^{11}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - I shall absorb it shortly. Mea culpa, I confused the reference in the comment with a *thesis* I'd read  by a student of *Zeilberger*'s, the intro is quite similar, so I thought "I've seen this before... and interacted with the author...", so I shall also read the reference completely. Expect an accept - just want to verify it's what I'm after (I think that important before accepting). Thanks again for the time taken.

Comment: Accepted - that does it perfectly. I'll be finishing the ref'd paper to completely grok the details, but I'm already able to see the estimator I've been using is surprisingly good for cases I could not test before, and now have the exact solution where needed. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good. Let me know if any questions or if something looks funny.